# Collect JSON objects with same attribute value, and create new key/value pairs

Tags: json, transformation, jq

Here is a simplified sample of the JSON data I'm working with:

```
[
  { "certname": "one.example.com",
    "name": "fact1",
    "value": "value1"
  },
  { "certname": "one.example.com",
    "name": "fact2",
    "value": 42
  },
  { "certname": "two.example.com",
    "name": "fact1",
    "value": "value3"
  },
  { "certname": "two.example.com",
    "name": "fact2",
    "value": 10000
  },
  { "certname": "two.example.com",
    "name": "fact3",
    "value": { "anotherkey": "anothervalue" }
  }
]
```

The result I want to achieve, using `jq` preferably, is the following:

```
[
  {
    "certname": "one.example.com",
    "fact1": "value1",
    "fact2": 42
  },
  {
    "certname": "two.example.com",
    "fact1": "value3",
    "fact2": 10000,
    "fact3": { "anotherkey": "anothervalue" }
  }
]
```

Its worth pointing out that not all elements have the same name/value pairs, by any means. Also, values are often complex objects in their own right.

If I was doing this in Python, it wouldn't be a big deal (and yes, I can hear the chorus of "do it in Python" ringing in my ears now). I would like to understand how to do this in `jq`, and it's escaping me at the moment.

Comment: Feel free to add a [python] tag to see what the pythonistas come up with :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... using jq preferably ...

That's the spirit!  And in that spirit, here's a concise solution:

```
map( {certname, (.name): .value} )
| group_by(.certname)
| map(add)
```

Of course there are other reasonable solutions.  If the above is at first puzzling, you might like to add a `debug` statement here or there, or you might like to explore the pipeline by executing the first line by itself, etc.

Comment: I'm unclear on why the `.name` part requires brackets around it, but other than that, when I did as you suggested and ran each part of the pipeline individually and in sequence (and doing some more doc reading) it makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: The parens are required whenever the key name is specified programatically.  The jq language designer wanted to allow the quotation marks around key named to be dropped, as in  `{a: 0}`, so it became important to distinguish between `{a:0}` and `{(a):0}`.  It would no doubt be possible to relax the syntactic requirements, but that would end up making things more complicated, both for users and implementers.